# What does RNG mean?

Tags: terminology

I think I've heard it in the context of speed-running Pokémon and other games. I think it means luck. It can be found around Arqade, but no one has asked what it means (as its own question).

Comment: Direct further comments here: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10382/what-does-rng-mean-comments-extension

Comment: The two answers so far have expanded the abbreviation, but they don't explain what random number generators have to do with video games. I'd add this to the original question instead of as a comment, but I don't want to bump the question and garner more downvotes.

Comment: I may be dyslexic because I have always thought of RNG as "randomly generated number" in my head...

Answer (score 18):

RNG stands for [random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation).

It is often used in speedruns, to say that you had luck (like "I got lucky with the RNG") or that a section can be quite random ("The RNG in this section can be a pain").

You might also hear [rngesus](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rngesus) ("pray to rngesus that it works") - basically praying for good luck.

Comment: Don't forget to pray to the RNGods.

Comment: don't forget the dreaded [desire sensor](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Desire+Sensor)

Comment: Notably in the context of Pokemon and other RPG-esque games (although not in the context of speed running), RNG is also commonly used to refer to (P)RNG abuse, that is, calculating and forcing specific "random" outcomes thanks to the fact that RNGs aren't actually generating *truly* random numbers, but rather pseudo-random numbers which only *look* random.